# My WordPress doesn't have the site logo feature?

Tags: logo

I just installed the latest version of WordPress (4.9.5) on my server, and I want to add a custom logo next to the title of my website.

Every tutorial mentions a feature called "site logo", but I cannot find this feature anywhere in my WordPress installation. I'm almost starting to question my own sanity at this point.

According to tutorials, I should have this option in the "Site identity" section, but it's not there. I do have a 'site icon' setting there, but this only seems to affect the favicon image. No logo is displayed on the site itself.

I also checked the "header image" section under "customize". This always me to upload an image, but this image is used as a background image for the header. That's not what I had I mind either.

I really feel like I'm missing something obvious here, so any help is very much appreciated.

PS: I'm using the free "sela" theme, which claims to support the site logo feature.

Answer (score 2):

Custom logo functionality has two parts, first your theme has to declare support for this feature with `add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );`, then you need to use `the_custom_logo` function to display it wherever you want in your template.

You can learn more from https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-logo/

Comment: Hi, I'm not the theme developer. The sela theme does support the custom-logo feature. My problem is that I cannot specify the logo image anywhere in my WordPress installation. Is this a feature that is only available on the hosted version of WordPress?

Comment: No, the feature is available with downloadable WordPress version, I've checked the theme and not seems to has support for this feature, you have to add it with the methods I've stated.

Comment: checking deeper I've found that it uses `jetpack_the_site_logo` that is only available when jetpack plugin is enabled